# Adjust time step in ode15s

Tags: matlab, ode

I'm solving a system of DAEs in MATLAB using the `ode15s` function, and at some point in the simulation, the solver is unable to reach the necessary tolerances, and execution terminates. If I reduce the maximum step size to a small value (~1e-5), the program is able to continue and reach the specified endpoint.

Based on the fact that reducing the time step allows the program to continue, I suspect that the `ode15s` script is taking too large a time step at some point and is unable to recover from it. However, maintaining this small maximum step means that I have thousands of unnecessary data points that slow down the simulation and take up space.

First, is it possible to have an adjustable maximum step size in `ode15s`? Everything I've found so far indicates that this is not possible, but I could be missing something.

If that isn't possible, I could approximate the behavior by waiting until the function gets past the critical time (i.e., the time at which the simulation would crash with no time step constraint), stop it, and restart with no time step constraint. However, I do not know the critical time a priori, and in the final simulation (the current one is highly simplified), I will have dozens of initial conditions at different locations, and so I will not be able to manually adjust all of the times in a reasonable amount of time. How would I go about finding the critical time in an automated manner so that I could adjust my step size once it is passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short one: max step size is defined once and can be changed during single computational process using standard MATLAB solvers.

Long one: I am quite sure that changing maximum step size dynamically is really tricky and not necessary. Step size can be changed between max and min values, that's all we get from variable step solvers.
You can try to change min step size value - the idea of such methods is to automatically adjust step size in case low convergence.[This](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/choosing-a-solver.html#bsc6i5t) page can provide some useful info about choosing and tuning solvers.

Splitting the problem for subproblems for reducing time bu changing steps is possible, but it will give more headache than profit. Also, I suppose that "critical point" can be moving on the time line for different initial conditions.

The ultimate advice has 2 parts:

1. Try to tune solver as described in Matlab docs. (I'd suggest to try Sparse Analytical option for solver Jacobian method).
2. Get more power by using [parallel computing](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/parallel-matlab-multiple-processors-and-multiple-cores.html) or better hardware (for full model).

One more useful [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html#oderefine) about tuning solvers.

Comment: Because my system is of DAEs, I have to use `ode15s` or `ode23t`, the latter of which hasn't given good results. I just tested `ode23t` on this particular section, and it got much farther with similar results, although it too crashed before reached the designated endpoint.

When you refer to parallel computing, you're referring to parallelizing the differential equations, correct?

Comment: @Aliden There is some info about solving ODE using Matlab parallel pool, possible starting point is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769248/how-does-the-parallelism-solve-the-ode-parameter-sweep-using-matlab)